# Optimize dependent loops openmp

Tags: c++, c, optimization, loops, openmp

I have a problem i would like parallelize two for loops with openmp.

how to optimize this loop with openmp :

```
void test(float** m,tab* t,int n){

    int i,j;
    float gain;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1;] j < n; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                gain=m[t[(i+n-1)%n]][t[j]] + m[t[i]][t[(j+1)%n]] - m[t[(i+n -1)%n]][t[i]] - m[t[j]][t[(j+1)%n]] 
                if (gain< 0)
                {
                    swapTab(t,i,j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thx.

Comment: First thing is to remove the `if (i != j)`...

Comment: just swap 2 element of array:

Comment: void swapTab(int* tab,int i,int j){
    int temp;
    temp = tab[i];
    tab[i] = tab[j];
    tab[j] = temp;
}

Comment: Then parallelising this will be difficult, as the order in which you traverse the elements matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oli Charlesworth points out the order of traversal of the elements in your matrices matters, so simply slapping a parallel for directive around the outermost loop won't work.

One option you do have would be to trade some space for time.  Make a copy of your array `T` (call it `T'`).  In iteration 1 you would replace your line:

```
swapTab(t,i,j)
```

with something like

```
 T'[j][i] = T[i][j]
```

(I'm not much of a C++ programmer so ignore defects in the syntax.)

In the second iteration you would want first to copy `T'` back to `T` and then carry on.  DON'T do that -- set up pointers (`Tnew`, `Told`, perhaps) to `T` and `T'` and switch the pointers around so that `Told` always points to the array to be read, and `Tnew` always points to the array to be written.